# Chosing optimal k and optimal distance-metric for k-means

Tags: clustering, k-means, distance-functions, optimal

I have a data-set with roughly 20-dimensions and millions of points which I want to cluster.

The goal is to find a set of clusters which:

- Are as distinct as possible from each other (minimum coupling) between clusters, i.e. maximum average distance between centroids
- With instances as similar as possible (maximum cohesion) inside the clusters, i.e. minimum average distance between the points within each cluster.

Without considering the domain, is there a good metric to help determine the ***optimal $k$ I should choose***?

Intuitively, I would pick $k=\sqrt{N}$ for a data-set in two dimensions, and $k=\sqrt[M]{N}$ for a data-set with $M$ dimensions and $N$ data-points, but I have a hunch that there are better methods.

A related and complementary question is ***which distance metric*** to use. Due to the curse of dimensionality, I know that euclidean distance becomes a poor choice as the number of dimensions increases.

*Note that this question is different than [Choosing optimal K for KNN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126051/choosing-optimal-k-for-knn/) (this one asks about clustering rather than `k-NN` classification)*

Comment: VTC as duplicate of [How to decide on the correct number of clusters?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23472/1352), which I found through [this search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22number+of+clusters%22+is%3Aquestion). And please don't ask multiple different questions in one post. [This search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distance+clustering+is%3Aquestion) may help you in your second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is plenty of literature on choosing k, such as the silhouette plot.
This question has also been asked a dozen times.

- [How to decide on the correct number of clusters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/how-to-decide-on-the-correct-number-of-clusters)
- [Determining number of clusters K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117461/determining-number-of-clusters-k-means?lq=1)
- [Elbow criteria to determine number of cluster](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/elbow-criteria-to-determine-number-of-cluster?lq=1)
- [How to define number of clusters in K-means clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/how-to-define-number-of-clusters-in-k-means-clustering?lq=1)
- [How to determine optimal number of clusters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/how-to-determine-optimal-number-of-clusters?lq=1)

Same for your second question - asked several times before:

- [Using k-means with other metrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/using-k-means-with-other-metrics)
- [Why does k-means clustering algorithm use only Euclidean distance metric?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric)
- [Distance function for categories in K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31308/distance-function-for-categories-in-k-means)
- [Is it possible to specify your own distance function using scikit-learn K-Means Clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means)
- [k-means implementation with custom distance matrix in input](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12495/k-means-implementation-with-custom-distance-matrix-in-input)
- [Perform K-means (or its close kin) clustering with only a distance matrix, not points-by-features data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32925/how-to-perform-k-means-clustering-with-only-a-distance-function-not-euclidean-p)

Do *not* use k-means with other distance functions than sum-of-squares. It may *stop converging*. **k-means is not distance based**. It minimizes the very classic sum of squares. The *mean* function is an L2 estimator of centrality - if you want to use a different distance function, you need to choose cluster centers differently. This has been done, see k-medoids aka PAM.

Don't forget to spend a lot of time preprocessing your data and visualizing your results. People tend to neglect that, and get really bad results without noticing... again, see other questions here on k-means.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found several related questions by searching for the kmeans tag. Some appear on the right as 'Related' but none of them answered these specific questions in a clear direct way. I now realize I should have asked about distance clustering rather than specifically about k-means. I'll look up Silhouette plots, thanks again.